# seeking syntax for date in where clause in Jet OLEDB

Tags: ruby, oledb

I have a problem of using the where clause for limiting dates

I can't even get a simple statement like on "Feb 5 2010" to work,
e.g.,

select * from LineItems where DueDate = 2/5/2010;
I tried
"2/5/2010"
"2010/2/5"
"2010-2-5"
"2010-02-05"
2010-2-5
2010-02-05
...
but none worked.

Does anyone have an idea what the proper format for the date should
be? And should it be quoted?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Guys, I did figured out that you must surround the date with a pair of #'s. Just leaving the date unsurrounded does not work for me. I figured this out by saving a "Filter" in the Data View of Access as query, then I looked at that query in SQL view.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in a Query

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
where mydate = 2010/2/5
```

Writing a date like that is unambiguous; the other way round will depend on your locale settings.

Comment: @Remou: true. But using the ISO-like format (i.e. yyyy/mm/dd) is still a good idea.

Comment: Absolutely! Even though the help files suggest American format. The comment was intended as small addition, rather than a complaint.